# Difference between p4diff and p4diff2

Tags: diff, perforce

What is the difference between P4 diff and P4 diff2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p4 diff` is used on the client, e.g. to compare a locally modified file to the version on the depot. `p4 diff2` is used to compare two files **on the server**.

From the manual:

```
$ p4 help diff

On the client machine, diff a client file against the corresponding
revision in the depot. The file is compared only if the file is
opened for edit or a revision is provided. See 'p4 help revisions'
for details about specifying revisions.

$ p4 help diff2

'p4 diff2' runs on the server to compare one set of depot files (the
'source') to another (the 'target').  Source and target file sets
can be specified on the 'p4 diff2' command line or through a branch
view.
```

Comment: Can you also tell which among the two is faster?

Comment: This is not about speed. diff vs. diff2 are two different use cases.

Comment: 'p4 diff2' runs entirely on the server, and sends the results to the client. It's likely to be faster than 'p4 diff', which sends original versions of files to the client, and launches and runs a diff program on the client machine. But that of course could depend on the size of the files, the speed of the network, and the efficiency of client-side diff program. However, as @jhwist said, it's not as if you get to choose. When comparing your local changes to the original depot versions, you must use 'p4 diff'. When comparing one depot version to another, you must use 'p4 diff2'.

Comment: can you help me to change the p4 diff2 commandline to a c# p4command